# Is strlen of a const char* optimised?

Tags: c, string, optimization, strlen

Can I use `strlen` of a `const char*` in a loop like this and expect O(n) time complexity, or would it result in O(n^2)? I think it looks cleaner than using a variable for the string length.

```
void send_str( const char* data ) {
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++)
        send_byte( data[i] );
}
```

Does it depend on the optimization level?

Comment: Even if strlen isn't, compiler should optimize it.

Comment: strlen(data) is an operation and will be executed every loop ,better a  variable to store value once and use ,since the method call will take place once if did so

Comment: I tested with both GCC and Clang; both call `strlen` in each round.

Comment: **NOT** optimization don't consider function (not even library).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think you can ever *depend* on an optimization happening.

Why not do it like this, if you really want to avoid an extra variable:

```
void send_str(const char *data)
{
  for(size_t i = strlen(data); i != 0; --i)
    send_byte(*data++);
}
```

Or, less silly, and more like an actual production-quality C program:

```
void send_str(const char *data)
{
  while(*data != '\0')
    send_byte(*data++);
}
```

There's no point at all in iterating over the characters twice, so don't call `strlen()` at all, detect the end-of-string yourself.

Comment: Yes, this is actually an XY problem ... +1 for paying attention to the OP's actual requirement.

Comment: Does sending 4 elements instead of 1, change the performance in this example? Such as checking against the address is divisible by 4, then starting 4 by 4, looking contents of data(if one is having null) before sending? Also if address is not divisible by 4, doing first 1-3 elements slowly then continuing 4 by 4?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler might optimize that, but perhaps not to the point you want it to. Obviously depending on the compiler version and the optimization level.

<sup>you might consider using the [MELT probe](http://gcc-melt.org/index.html#probe_id) to understand what GCC is doing with your code (e.g. what internal Gimple representation is it transformed to by the compiler). Or `gcc -fverbose-asm -O -S` to get the produced assembler code.</sup>

However, for your example, it is simpler to code:

```
 void send_str(const char*data) {
    for (const char*p = data; *p != 0; p++)
        send_byte(*p);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the definition of `send_byte()` is not available when this code is compiled (eg. it's in another translation unit), then this probably *can't* be optimised in the way you describe.  This is because the `const char *` pointer doesn't guarantee that the object pointed to really is `const`, and therefore the `send_byte()` function could legally modify it (`send_byte()` may have access to that object via a global variable).

For example, were `send_byte()` defined like so:

```
int count;
char str[10];

void send_byte(char c)
{
    if (c == 'X')
        str[2] = 0;
    count++;
}
```

and we called the provided `send_str()` function like so:

```
count = 0;
strcpy(str, "AXAXAX");
send_str(str);
```

then the result in `count` must be 2.  If the compiler hoisted the `strlen()` call in `send_str()` out of the loop, then it would instead be 6 - so this would not be a legal transform for the compiler to make.

Comment: -1, `send_byte()` just gets a single character passed by value, it cannot modify anything.

Comment: @unwind: `send_byte()` could have access to the same object via a global variable.